# JSON Data parsing is not working

Tags: javascript, html, json

guys please see Javascript code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.loader').hide();
getDataUsers("userCount");
var obj = JSON.parse($("#hdUserCount").val());
userChart(obj.Actives, obj.InActives, obj.Discountinued, obj.recentlyJoined);
});
function userChart(act, inact, disc, recent) {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("userChart", {

                                   title: {
        text: "Users"

    },
                                   animationEnabled: true,
                                   axisX: {
        interval: 1,
        gridThickness: 0,
        labelFontSize: 10,
        labelFontStyle: "normal",
        labelFontWeight: "normal",
        labelFontFamily: "Lucida Sans Unicode"

    },
                                   axisY2: {
        interlacedColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.2)",
        gridColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.1)"

    },

                                   data: [{
                                               type: "bar",
                                               name: "Users",
                                               axisYType: "secondary",
                                               color: "#014D65",
                                               dataPoints: [

                                                   { y: act, label: "Active" },
                                                   { y: inact, label: "InActive" },
                                                   { y: disc, label: "DisContinued" },
                                                   { y: recent, label: "Recently Joined" },
                                               ]
                                           }

    ]
                               });

chart.render();
}
function getDataUsers(flagData) {
$('.loader').fadeIn('fast');
$.post("Stats.ashx", {
           flag: flagData,
       }, function (data, status) {
           $("#hdUserCount").val(data);
           $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
           alert(data);
       });
}
```

and the problem is that when it runs in debug mode in FireBug and line 3 to 5 has break point there is no problem, and every thing is good.
BUT! when I remove break points I think some parts of the code are not being executed!!! wired!!! I think the part that parses the JSON data is not working!!!

and this is the data received by post:

> {"Actives": 3, "InActives": 4, "Discountinued": 0, "recentlyJoined": 6}

Comment: I'd try adding some `console.log()` in the blocks you think are not executed...

Comment: That's not how asynchronous code works. When you are trying to `JSON.parse` the content of that DIV, the post request is still in progress, and therefore, there is no `data` yet in your div.

Comment: Nice! Thats obviously the reason! but should I make my post synchronous???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how asynchronous code works. This is what your function should look like:

```
function getDataUsers(flagData, callback) {
    $('.loader').fadeIn('fast');
    $.post("Stats.ashx", {
           flag: flagData,
           }, function (data, status) {
               callback(data);
           }
     });
 }
```

And then you call it like:

```
getDataUsers('userCount', function(data) {
      $("#hdUserCount").val(data);
      $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
      var obj = JSON.parse($("#hdUserCount").val());
      // Add the rest of code that relies on obj .. 
}
```

Comment: Neat and Nice! Thanks. Just done it like your Example! so the delay made by break point was the reason that the code were executed Correctly?